# "Windows Installer" is not adding the program into start menu

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, installation

I created a Windows form application for my C# project using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766795.aspx) guide. However I selected "setup wizard". It created a nice installer but the issue is when  the program is installed, it is not getting added to the start menu and not creating any desktop icon. Why is this?

This is the first time I have tried this anyway. The .net version I am using for this project is 2.0.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to follow these [steps](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837220) or

1. From Solution Explorer click your setup project.
2. Click File System Editor (on top of Solution Explorer).
3. When File System Editor has opened, on left tab you can see "File System on Target Machine". Click Application Folder.
4. Then on the left tab the "Primary output from MyApp (Active)" appears. Right click it and select "Create shortcut to Primary output from MyApp (Active)". You should now see the shortcut appear below the primary output, which is your application executable.
5. Drag & Drop that shortcut from right tab to left tabs File System on Target Machine - User's Desktop folder and start menu.
6. Now the shortcut to your exe will appear on the desktop after install.
7. You can click the shortcut in File System Editor and edit the Name property from Properties grid to change the text that appears on the icon.